# NETWORK_ERROR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 in blackberry browser

Tags: jquery

I am writing a web application in which I am using `jQuery.ajax()` for `HTTP GET, POST, PUT` operations. In blackberry mobile browser, this is not working and giving the following error.

Error:

```
NETWORK_ERROR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

In iphone browser, this is working fine. Can any one help me out in solving this.

Thanks
Srikant K